# Posting to controller via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send a :vote parameter of 'up' to my controller, so that it performs the voting function of current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@book). I am using the thumbs up gem.

I am trying to do this using link_to, and the correct parameters are showing up in my server output, but it is not working with the controller. I must be doing something wrong, but I am not sure what. Do i need to do something different with routes, other than books :resources?

This my vote action in books_controller

```
 def vote
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if params[:vote] == 'up'
      current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@book)
    end
      redirect_to @book
 end
```

And this is the link_to example in my view:

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", :url => { :controller => "books", :action => "vote", :vote => "up"}, :method => :post %>
```

Any advice on where my attempts are breaking down would be greatly appreciated ( extra note: when i put the current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@book) function in my view it works) so I think this is a view/routes/link_to issue, not the function itself.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working with the controller"? Is your controller code being executed? Are you seeing an error somewhere? What is the output of running 'rake routes'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your link_to. It seems to be missing the ID of the book it's voting on?

Make sure your routes.rb file looks like this:

```
resources :books do
  post :vote, :on => :member
end
```

Then change your link_to function to this:

```
 link_to "Vote Up", vote_book_path(@book, :vote => "up"), :method => :post
```

Comment: I put get instead of post in the resources, not sure why this worked...but it did! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and solved it by using this style syntax:

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", {:controller => "books", :action => :vote, :vote => "up" }, {:method => :post} %>
```

Also make sure your routes.rb has something similar to

```
resources books do
  post :vote
end
```